# I can't generate a local source-map from a parent directory using UglifyJS2 CLI

Tags: uglifyjs, uglifyjs2

I'm trying to minify `www/js/app.js` to `www/js/app.min.js` with a source-map: `www/js/app.min.js.map`.

I also want `app.min.js` to contain the line `//# sourceMappingURL=app.min.js.map`

Is this possible to achieve without using the `cd` command?

So far this is the only thing that works for me:
`cd www/js && uglifyjs app.js --mangle --compress --stats --source-map app.min.js.map --output app.min.js && cd ../../`

I have been referencing https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2#usage `--source-map [options]` but nothing seems to work, so maybe I'm missing something obvious.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, their guide is very misleading in the source-mapping options!

I've found one should use `--source-map includeSources` or `--source-map url "url"` for it to work.

UPDATE: if `url` or `root` has spaces in it, you can put all between double and single quotes, eg: `--source-map "root='<URL>'"`